# How connect to webservice with generated c files from wsdl2c

Tags: c, web-services, wsdl, client, stub

I used axis2c to generate c files from a wsdl file. ([this is the WSDL file I used](http://t320webservices.open.ac.uk/t320/services/HelloService?wsdl))
now I have these list of files:

```
adb_helloName.c
adb_helloNameResponse.c
axis2_extension_mapper.c
axis2_stub_HelloService.c
plus I have their header files. and a HelloServiceClient.vcproj file.
```

I created a project in visual studio and now I want to know how can I connect to the webservice and get the return values. (in this case I have a hello world wsdl file that gets a name and passes "Hello + (thatName)")

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I tried to create my own server with my own wsdl file.

I created a server in JAVA that gets 2 number values and add them together:

```
public class Math {

   public int addOperator(int num1, int num2){
      return (num1+num2);
   }
}
```

then I created the WSDL file from it in Eclipse.
from the WSDL file I created the c files :

> adb_addOperator.c
>
> adb_addOperatorResponse.c
>
> axis2_extension_mapper.c
>
> axis2_stub_MathService.c
>
> plus I have their header files.
>
> MathServiceClient.vcproj file.

I imported this project in visual studio.
Then I added This math.c file to my project:

```
#include "axis2_stub_MathService.h"

int main(
    int argc,
    char *argv) 
{
    axutil_env_t * env = NULL;
    axis2_char_t * operation = NULL;
    axis2_char_t * client_home = NULL;
    axis2_char_t * endpoint_uri = NULL;
    axis2_stub_t * stub = NULL;
    adb_addOperatorResponse_t * add_res = NULL;
    adb_addOperator_t * add_in = NULL;
    int res_val = 0;
    endpoint_uri = "http://localhost:8080/AddOperator/services/Math"; //this is the tomcatServer running the MathServer
    env = axutil_env_create_all("alltest.log", AXIS2_LOG_LEVEL_TRACE);
    
    /* Set up deploy folder. */ 
    client_home = AXIS2_GETENV("AXIS2C_HOME");
    if (!client_home)
        client_home = "../../../deploy";
    stub = axis2_stub_create_MathService(env, client_home, endpoint_uri);
    add_in = adb_addOperator_create(env);   
    adb_addOperator_set_num1(add_in, env, 14); //initializing num1
    adb_addOperator_set_num2(add_in, env, 33); //initializing num2
    add_res = axis2_stub_op_MathService_addOperator(stub, env, add_in);
    if (!add_res)
        
    {
        printf("Error: response NULL\n");
        return -1;
    }
    res_val = adb_addOperatorResponse_get_addOperatorReturn(add_res, env);
    printf("Add Result : %d ", res_val);    

    return 0;
}
```

compiled the project. and then I opened cmd and I opened the MathService.exe directory. then I ran the MathService.
It worked properly.